# purrr's map works, but furrr's future map does not

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

In the following code, map_dfr from purrr works, but the future_map_dfr from furrr throws an error. How can I fix it?

```
    #install.packages("randomForest"); install.packages("tidyverse"); install.packages("iml")
    library(tidyverse); library(iml); library(randomForest) 
    library(furrr)

    plan(multiprocess)

    set.seed(42)

    mtcars1 <- mtcars %>%  mutate(vs = as.factor(vs),
                                  id = row_number())

x <- "vs"
y <- paste0(setdiff(setdiff(names(mtcars1), "vs"), "id"), collapse = "+")

rf = randomForest(as.formula(paste0(x, "~ ", y)), data = mtcars1, ntree = 50)

predictor <- Predictor$new(rf, data = mtcars1, y = mtcars1$vs)

# Results using map_dfr() from purrr
shapelyresults <- map_dfr(1:nrow(mtcars), ~(Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = mtcars1[.x,]) %>% 
                                              .$results %>% 
                                              as_tibble() %>% 
                                              arrange(desc(phi)) %>% 
                                              slice(1:5) %>% 
                                              select(feature.value, phi) %>%
                                              mutate(id = .x)))

# Attempt to use future_map_dfr() from furrr
f_shapelyresults <- future_map_dfr(1:nrow(mtcars), ~(Shapley$new(predictor, x.interest = mtcars1[.x,]) %>% 
                                              .$results %>% 
                                              as_tibble() %>% 
                                              arrange(desc(phi)) %>% 
                                              slice(1:5) %>% 
                                              select(feature.value, phi) %>%
                                              mutate(id = .x)))
```

Comment: This issue also occurs if you use the `future_lapply()` function from the `future.apply` package, so it seems plausible that the issue has something to do with the interaction between the modeling packages being used (`iml`, etc.) and the `futures` package, rather than being isolated to the `furrr` package.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the detailed explanation, bschneidr! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

`furrr`, which utilizes `future`, depending on your configuration, may use R subprocesses mapped to different CPU cores or threads with their own environments/scopes.

Two general types of issue tend to crop up, in my experience:

1. Packages aren't always attached right by the subprocesses.
2. Objects aren't always accessible by the subprocesses.

Accordingly, you might:
- Rewrite your `purrr` lambda functions as named functions, and throw `require()` calls at the top of the functions to rule out the first type of issue.
- In your named function, pass your secondary data as an argument as well.

Try something like this:

```r
library(furrr)

my_function <-
  function(primary_object, Shapely_object) {

    require(tidyverse); require(iml); require(randomForest) 

    Shapley_object$new(predictor, 
                       x.interest = mtcars1[primary_object, ]) %>%
      .$results %>%
      as_tibble() %>%
      arrange(desc(phi)) %>%
      slice(1:5) %>%
      select(feature.value, phi) %>%
      mutate(id = primary_object))
  }

f_shapelyresults <- 
  future_map_dfr(
   .x = 1:nrow(mtcars), # 1st argument: primary_object, above
   .f = my_function,
   Shapely_object = Shapely # 2nd argument, as seen above
  )
```

Comment: I had errors running `forecastHybrid::hybridModel()` on nested time series, with 2 arguments within `future_map2()`. Rewriting my lambda function as named function solved it.